# cx_oracle.NotsupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported when executing query in python

Tags: python, sql, tuples

I have below python code which is giving error cx_oracle.NotsupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported.

```
query= "update cloud_events set processing= :processing where event_type= :event"
conn.connect()
cursor= conn.get_cursor()
cursor.execute(query,[processing,event])
conn.commit()
```

What could be the issue

Comment: Is anybody able to help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by updating code like below

```
query= "update cloud_events set processing= :processing where event_type= :event"
conn.connect()
cursor= conn.get_cursor()
cursor.execute(query,processing,event)
conn.commit()
```